# Angular Universal (Angular 16) does not display data loaded from API in Page Source

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-ssr

I am building a website with Angular 16 and it's now time to add Angular universal to add SSR and display HTML in my browser for SEO perposes.

I have followed the Angular documentation here to install Angular Universal Express Engine (screenshot below)
[image]

When I run the command **"npm run dev:ssr"** to run the website, the HTML that I directly write in my component appears in the page source,
**BUT** the data that I am fetching from an API call does not appear in the Page source, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

HTML written directly in component appears
[image]

### **API data not appearing on the page source**

[image]

Please help!

Comment: What backend stack are you using? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Do you use the `HttpClient` to load your data  ?

Comment: Yes, using HttpClient to talk to a local ASP.NET Core Web API